# Getting error from web service method after publish "Maximum response size reached"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

Published `GetDocument` Web Method and it will return the **File Name** along with **File Content**, which is **Base64 text** of the File and it's working fine. But when we request more than **120MB** file getting error **Error: Maximum response size reached**.

**Actual:**

For this I tried the below code in c#.

```
[WebMethod]
        public DocumentResponse GetDocument(string AuthTokenKey, string FileNameWithPath)
        {
            using (File_Information fs = new File_Information())
                return fs.GetDocumentResponse(AuthTokenKey, FileNameWithPath);
        }

private class File_Information
{

DocumentResponse ObjDocumentResponse;

public DocumentResponse GetDocumentResponse(string AuthTokenKey, string FileNameWithPath)
        {
if (ObjDocumentResponse == null)
                ObjDocumentResponse = new DocumentResponse();

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileNameWithPath);
 ObjDocumentImportFile.Add(new DocumentImportFile
                                            {
                                                FileName = StrFileName,
                                                FileContent = GetFileContent(fileInfo.FullName)
                                            });
            
            ObjDocumentResponse.DocumentImportFile = ObjDocumentImportFile;
            

            return ObjDocumentResponse;

}

private string GetFileContent(string name)
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(name);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes);
        }

}
```

After getting error of Maximum response size reached, I have modified the `web.config` file to accept/allowed the maximum response size.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2048576000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2048576000"  />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Still getting the same Error.

**Expecting:**
Require to return the File Content of Base64 text at least **500MB** from the method.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I turn the setting into **350MB** now working.

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="350000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Require to check more than **350MB** file with increasing timeout time.